# Creating subplots in loop iterating through dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, subplot

I am fairly new to python, to begin with the question. My data is stored as three arrays (x, y and z) in varying number of sheets in excel worksheet, such that data in each sheet of the excel file constitute as a subplot and should be sub plotted altogether as shown [image: here].

In this case there were three sheets.

Excel spreadsheet loaded using `pd.read_excel` in the form of dictionary contains each sheets as key with data for subplots. As there are varying number of sheets, I wish to sub-plot all the sheets in loop such that the loop reads each dataframe within the dictionary and creates a composite figure containing all the subplots representing each sheets, preferably, in a common x-axis.

I have tried the following code but it creates individual plots which are saved separately needing me to manually compile them together using raster graphic editor software.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


loc = r'E:\Python\data.xlsx'
load = pd.read_excel(loc,sheet_name = None, header=None)

nar=list(load.keys())
nplots = len(nar)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=nplots, ncols=1, sharex=True)
for k in load:
    dem=load[k]
    x=np.array(dem[0])
    y=np.array(dem[1])
    z=np.array(dem[2])

# creating different limits for contour lines
    lmin=dem[2].min()
    lmax=dem[2].max()
    progn=(lmax-lmin)/10
    progn2=(lmax-lmin)/20
    progn0=(lmax-lmin)/5
    limit=np.arange(lmin,lmax,progn)
    limit0=np.arange(lmin,lmax,progn0)
    limit2=np.arange(lmin,lmax,progn2)
    

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,4))

#cline,mcline are contour lines and con is contour fill

    cline=ax.tricontour(x,y,z,limit0, color='k')   
        
    mcline=ax.tricontour(x,y,z,limit)

    con=ax.tricontourf(x, y, z, limit2, cmap='rainbow')
    plt.colorbar(con, shrink=.5)

    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    plt.savefig(str(k)+'.png', dpi=300)
    plt.show()
```

I would like to request an expert to help me in achieving the desired looping technique. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You call `plt.subplots()` twice, once before the for loop, and once inside the loop. The former call is the only one you want. Instead of

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,4))
```

which creates a new Figure with new subplots, you want to use your existing axes which are a part of the figure you already created

```
ax = axs[i]
```

where i is the number of the current plot you want to edit.

Comment: Thank you @Keon for taking up interest in my question. Can you please suggest more on how to define `i`?

Comment: One example would be modifying your loop to use "for i, k in enumerate(load):" That will give you an index for each new plot you're making. You could also simply define i = 0 before your for loop, and do i+=1 at the bottom of it.